# Select next available date and join to another table

Tags: sql

I am trying to select the next available date from one table and link it to another table.

The main table is a list of products for which I have columns such as price size etc. In the second table I have the product ID, a list of dates and whether the product is available or not. The dates are from a point in the past to a point in the future.

I want to filter the dates so that they are greater or equal to today and showing as available. Then add the next available date into my main dataset with the product information.

**Table 1**:
`Product ID, Product Name, Price, Size`

**Table 2**:
`ProductID, Dates, Available (0/1)`

I have tried to `left join table 2 to table 1 and use WHERE to set dates >= to today and available to 1`.

I have tried a nested SELECT statement as other question responses have suggested but the outcome of this is that the same date is linked to every product ID which is not right.

Guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below example.

Lets assume first table is Product_Details having below columns

ProductID, ProductName, Price, Size

Another table is Available_products with below columns

ProductID, Dates, Available

please find the query

```
select pd.ProductID,pd.ProductName,pd.Price,pd.Size  from Product_Details pd, Available_products pa where pa.ProductID=pd.ProductID and DATE(pa.Dates) >= DATE(NOW()) and pa.Available=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Raj Paliwal's answer, but with current SQL Server syntax.

**Products** table: ProductId, ProductName, Price, Size (PK: ProductId)

**ProductDates** table: ProductId, DateStart, IsAvailable (PK: ProductId, DateStart)

```
SELECT  A.ProductId,
        A.ProductName,
        A.Price,
        A.Size,
        B.DateStart,
        B.IsAvailable
FROM    #Product as A
        INNER JOIN #ProductDates as B
            ON A.ProductId = B.ProductId
WHERE   DateStart >= convert(date, getdate())
    AND IsAvailable = 1

--  Output (where current date is 2019-10-25):
--  ProductId   ProductName         Price   Size    DateStart   IsAvailable
--  ----------- -----------         ------- ------- ----------- -----------
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-10-28  1
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-11-03  1
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-11-05  1
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-11-06  1
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-11-11  1
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-11-12  1
--  100         Sample 100 Product  59.00   16      2019-11-13  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-10-28  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-11-03  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-11-04  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-11-05  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-11-06  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-11-11  1
--  200         Sample 200 Product  12.00   8       2019-11-12  1
--  300         Sample 300 Product  44.23   21.5    2019-11-03  1
--  300         Sample 300 Product  44.23   21.5    2019-11-04  1
--  300         Sample 300 Product  44.23   21.5    2019-11-06  1
--  300         Sample 300 Product  44.23   21.5    2019-11-11  1
--  300         Sample 300 Product  44.23   21.5    2019-11-12  1
```

Note: In the real world, the price would probably also be date sensitive as well as the availability. So that column would be in the **ProductDates** table.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have applied the above, but the problem I have is that I only want to see the first available date row for each product ID. For example: ID 100 date 28/10/19, ID 200 28/10/19, ID 300 3/11/19. I don't want to see all available dates. How can I pull just the first available date that is in the future? Thank you

Comment: Actually, I think I have done it by adding a MIN clause to the date: SELECT  A.ProductID,
        MIN(B.StartDate) AS [Date],
        B.IsAvailable
FROM    #Product as A
        INNER JOIN #ProductDates as B
            ON A.ProductID = B.ProductID
WHERE   StartDate >= convert(date, getdate())
    AND Available = 1

GROUP BY A.PropertyID, B.IsAvailable